# Cant display an image where image path is stored in a Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I am trying display images on webpage, where image path stored in database and images is stored in server.But i am not able to display those images using following codes, so pls somebody help me with this issue,..

[image]

```
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file_upload.php">
<table>

<?php

$dbhost = 'xxxxxxxx';
$dbuser = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$db_name = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$tbl_name = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$query1 = mysql_query("select * from '$tbl_name' where id='1'");
$rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
$path1 = $rows1['image'];

$query2 = mysql_query("select * from '$tbl_name' where id='2'");
$rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
$path2 = $rows2['image'];

$query3 = mysql_query("select * from '$tbl_name' where id='3'");
$rows3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3);
$path3 = $rows3['image'];

echo '<tr><td><img src="$path1"></td>' ;
echo '<td><img src="$path2"></td>' ;
echo '<td><img src="$path3"></td></tr>' ;

?>

</form>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look à this code :

```
$b = "aaaaaaa";

echo '"$b"';  // will displayt "$b"
echo "'$b'";  // will displayt 'aaaaaaa'
echo "\"$b\"";// will displayt "aaaaaaa"

enter code here
```

So, for your problem it's simply because if you want a variable to be evaluated in string you must put it between "" and not ''.

```html
<table>
<?php 
 $path1 = "/upload/image1.png";
 $path2 = "/upload/image2.png";
 $path3 = "/upload/image3.png";
 
 echo "<tr><td><img src='$path1'></td>" ;
 echo "<td><img src='$path2'></td>" ;
 echo "<td><img src='$path3'></td></tr>" ;
?>
</table>
```

Or

```html
<table>
<?php 
 $path1 = "/upload/image1.png";
 $path2 = "/upload/image2.png";
 $path3 = "/upload/image3.png";
 
 echo '<tr><td><img src="'.$path1.'"></td>' ;
 echo '<td><img src="'.$path2.'"></td>' ;
 echo '<td><img src="'.$path3.'"></td></tr>' ;
?>
</table>
```

Anas

Comment: I recommend to use the second version as it shows clearly where your html markup is and where your php variables are (concatenated by the period).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `uploads` directory in the current path,  try the following - notice the `period` in front of $pathX telling, it is current directory.

```
echo '<tr><td><img src=".$path1"></td>' ;
echo '<td><img src=".$path2"></td>' ;
echo '<td><img src=".$path3"></td></tr>' ;
```

Comment: Nothing is happening, its displaying ".$path1" only not path.

Answer (score 0):

(Stop using **mysql_*** functions as they are depreciated long back)

Use **mysqli** or **PDO**

in your example use loop so that easily access all the rows in resultset like below

```
$query1 = mysql_query("select * from ".$tbl_name);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$rows['image'];
?>
<tr><td><img src="<?=$path?>"></td>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
mysql_query("select * from '$tbl_name' where id='3'");
```

to

```
mysql_query("select * from '".$tbl_name."' where id='3'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>

<?php

try
{
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'password');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM '$tbl_name'")->fetch();

echo '<tr>';

foreach($query as $k => $v){
    echo '<td><img src="' . $v['image'] . '"></td>' ;
}

echo '</tr>';
?>

</table>
```

Comment: Your site is online ? If yes tell me the link pls, if not look at the inspector element.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try it**

<table>

    <?php

    $dbhost = 'xxxxxxxx';
    $dbuser = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    $dbpass = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    $db_name = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    $tbl_name = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    if(!$conn )
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name");
    while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    echo '<tr>';

        echo "<td><img src='". $v['image'] ."' width='200' height='200'></td>" ;
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>

    </form>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with your queries:

```
mysql_query("select * from '$tbl_name' where id='3'");
```

if you write it like this, the variable $tbl_name doesn't get resolved.

Try it like this:

```
mysql_query("select * from '".$tbl_name."' where id='3'");
```

same for the src-attribute of the image elements